# IMG tag is not accepting image URL in flask by using

Tags: python, html, image, flask, jinja2

code snapshot for my code error which is getting by flask jinja2 while using into html to get images by giving url through jinja2

```
{% for book in books %}

<div class="swiper-slide box">
  <div class="icons">
    <a href="#" class="fas fa-search"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fas fa-heart"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fas fa-eye"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="static/image/{{book['img']}}" alt="{{book['img']}}" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="{{book['url']}}" class="btn">Read</a>
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's to do with how you are accessing your static files, try in the format:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='images/image_name.jpg') }}
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/

Comment: but I'm fetching images from mongodb in which I store image name and link in the form of dictionary so I'm using "book['img'] and book['url']" in Html page

Answer (score 0):

I see, try:

```
 <img src="static/image/{{book.img}}" alt="{{book.img}}" />
```